# MVT / MVC with Django's admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

These are simple versions of my Models:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_ips(self):
        return self.deviceip_set.all()

    def get_ips_string(self):
        return ', '.join('<a href="http://' + unicode(ip.ip) + '">' + unicode(ip.ip) + '</a>' for ip in self.get_ips())

class DeviceIP(models.Model):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
```

And this is from my admin.py:

```
class DeviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__unicode__', 'get_ips_string')

admin.site.register(Device, DeviceAdmin)
```

From an MVT/MVC point of view, should methods like `get_ips_string()` be defined in the model or would they be better suited somewhere else (like admin.py) as they actually generate HTML?

If I decided to create my own templates instead of using the admin site, would that have an impact on where methods like `get_ips_string()` should be defined?

Answer (score 0):

1. Where are you going to use these methods? If you use them only in admin, it is appropriate to put them into corresponding `ModelAdmin` classes and reference in `fields`, `fieldsets`, or `list_display`. So, `ModelAdmin` corresponds to the View layer.
2. From the point of view of your template, these functions are just read-only model fields. No special status.

**P. S.** For Django admin customization, you may find `django-grappelli` (http://grappelliproject.com) or `xadmin` (http://demo.xadmin.io) inspiring.